# Creating and plotting a Binomial GLM

Tags: r, data-modeling, glm

I am trying to create a Binomial GLM with a logistic link to model my data. The variables
are: age (age group; 25-29, 30-39 or 40-49), education (educational level; high or low), wantsMore (may want more children in longer term; yes or no), using (number of women using contraception) and notUsing (number of women not using contraception).

I am trying to predict the number of numbers of women not using contraception using the education, age and wantsMore variables.

I have set up my model as seen below but I cant get it to work due to error messages, also shown below. Does anyone know where I have gone wrong in setting up the model?

my model

```
my_model = glm(cbind(notUsing, using-notUsing) ~ age + education + wantsMore,
      data = contraceptive2,
      family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

error message

```
Error in family$linkfun(mustart) : Value 7.64286 out of range (0, 1)
```

Assume this is linked to my explanatory variables but unsure how to change it

My dataframe

```
    head(contraceptive2)
    age education wantsMore notUsing using
1   <25       low       yes       53     6
2   <25       low        no       10     4
3   <25      high       yes      200    52
4   <25      high        no       50    10
5 25-29       low       yes       60    14
6 25-29       low        no       19    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two column matrix in the left hand side of the formula should contain "successes" and "failures", i.e. in this case "notUsing" and "using" (or vice-versa).  You don't want to subtract the successes from the failures.  Apart from anything this data would have a negative number of failures!  Try:

```
my_model = glm(cbind(notUsing, using) ~ age + education + wantsMore,
  data = contraceptive2,
  family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Comment: Perfect, that explains my other error of negative values. Also, do you know if it's possible to plot this model using ggplot? Slightly confused how we treat the X and Y variables if it is possible now they have been binded together